# How to force a newline after subsection?

Tags: line-breaking

I am trying to force a newline after subsection. How can i do that?
I am using conference documentclass.

Instead of

```
1. Subsection: This is a boy
```

i want

```
1. Subsection
This is a boy
```

Comment: in latex standard classes, the text does indeed start on a new line after a `\subsection` ... so please provide a minimal example of what you're doing.

Comment: Please provide a bit more detail about *which* document class named "conference" you use -- there's more than once such class. Providing an MWE (minimum working example) that generates the problem to be fixed would be most welcome.

Comment: The standard classes do that automatically, but the point of a conference class is that the conference organisers not the authors get to choose a uniform, possibly different, style so while you could redefine the sections back to article class layout that would defeat the purpose of using the specified class.

Comment: If this is a conference class you have been given to write a contribution, then *DO NOT CHANGE THE LAYOUT*. This will really annoy the conference editors. You provide the content, not the layout.